# UIImageView with setInteractionEnable = YES; handle click (tap) when it is beneath UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have one UIImageView that the user can move with panGesture. And he can move it under an UIButton. But when this situation appears, the user can't click on the UIButton anymore, he has to move the ImageView away first.

The touchBegan method is called (but the touched view is the ImageView, never the UIButton) and the "touch Up Inside" event of the UIButton is not called.

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using the following line of code whenever imageview overlaps on the button.So that button appears above the imageview.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: button];
```

To check if imageview overlaps on button use the following code.

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.bounds, button.bounds);
```

Comment: The button is already in the front. I can move the imageview beneath it. But i can't click on it.

Comment: you cant click on button?